# Custom WPF Slider with Triangular Thumb

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, customization

My goal is to make a slider like this:

[image: Desired Slider]

The problem is, when I move the slider to it's max value, the point of the triangle won't reach the top at the max value, it stays like this:

[image: Max value]

The reason I believe it's because the `Thumb's` position is restricted to it's size so it can't go beyond the limits of the slider....but in my case that's exactly what I want to achieve! I tried to change the `Thumb` height but this might help in the `Top`, but then it will be a problem in the `Bottom` of the slider.

What's missing in my code?

My code so far is:

The Slyder:

```
<Slider Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Maximum="1000" 
        Orientation="Vertical" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="20,0,20,20"
        Height="150" 
        Style="{DynamicResource LampadaSliderStyle}" />
```

The Repeat Button Style:

```
<Style x:Key="SliderRepeatButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The Thumb Style:

```
<Style x:Key="LampadaThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Canvas SnapsToDevicePixels="true">                        
                    <Path Data="M8.1965079,-17.994989 L28.196667,-28.213333 28.196333,-8.213772 z" 
                          Fill="Black" 
                          Height="20" 
                          Canvas.Left="23.197" 
                          Stretch="Fill" 
                          Canvas.Top="9.768" 
                          Width="20"/>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The Slider Style:

```
<Style x:Key="LampadaSliderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}" Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <UniformGrid x:Name="TrackBackground" 
                                     Rows="6" 
                                     Columns="0">
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" />
                            <Rectangle Fill="Orange" />
                            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" />
                            <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" />
                            <Rectangle Fill="Green" />
                            <Rectangle Fill="DarkGreen" />
                        </UniformGrid>
                        <Canvas Margin="-1,-6">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" 
                                               Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" 
                                               Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" 
                                               StrokeThickness="1.0" 
                                               Visibility="Hidden" 
                                               Width="4.0"/>
                        </Canvas>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track">
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}" Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{DynamicResource LampadaThumbStyle}"/>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I made them by editing the default template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest adjustment you can do is set a top margin of `10` (a half of the `Path`'s Height) so that the track background is put down enough for the triangle tip to match:

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="TrackBackground" Rows="6" Columns="0" 
             Margin="0,10,0,0">
     <!-- ... -->
</UniformGrid>
```

You have UniformGrid at more than 1 place, so edit them accordingly.

Comment: Well, this does the trick....but I will always have a margin in my control, I would rather not depend on this...

Comment: @mFeinstein it's not the margin of your control, it's the margin of the ***inner control***. Not sure why you refuse to such a beautiful solution. Without using Margin like this, I am ***sure*** that the other way is very complicated (and may involve code behind).

Comment: The bounds of your control still contains the triangle right at the top edge, I mean there is not any margin between the top horizontal line (going through the top vertex of the triangle) and the top border of your control.

Comment: And I had to actully make the Margin equal the Paths Height, I am not sure why...I guess it's related to how the Slider calculates the position of the Thumb...

Comment: I simplified the code, so now there is only one UniformGrid